# How to check if SVN credentials are correct and SVN server is running

Tags: python, svn, monitoring, credentials

I'm trying to write a Python application that will be able to determine if various SVN servers configurations are proper. This means server is accessible and credentials are correct. What is the easiest and convienient way to achieve this?

Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well the easiest way would be to use a library like [pysvn](http://pysvn.tigris.org/) and simply try to fetch the info of your svn repositories.

Comment: This seems to be okay, but how can I fetch the information about wrong credentials? Pysvn is calling callback_get_login over and over in case the username or password are wrong... Is there any way to determine it and stop prompting? May be pysvn or any other Python library.